# adding keys in nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

```
elements = {'hydrogen': {'number': 1, 'weight': 1.00794, 'symbol': 'H'}, 
            'helium': {'number': 2, 'weight': 4.002602, 'symbol': 'He'}}
```

Add an `is_noble_gas` boolean entry to the hydrogen and helium dictionaries.

Comment: Show us your code. See how to make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: elements['hydrogen']['is_noble_gas'] = False

Answer (score 3):

You should access the dictionary and add `is_noble_gas` as a new key to the dictionary as follows.

```
>>> elements['hydrogen']['is_noble_gas'] = False
>>> elements['helium']['is_noble_gas'] = True
```

Answer (score 2):

```
elements = {'hydrogen': {'number': 1, 'weight': 1.00794, 'symbol': 'H'}, 'helium': {'number': 2, 'weight': 4.002602, 'symbol': 'He'}}
noble_dict = { "hydrogen": False, "helium": True }
for noble in noble_dict:
    elements[ noble ][ "is_noble_gas" ] = noble_dict[ noble ]
```

> {'helium': {'symbol': 'He', 'number': 2, 'weight': 4.002602, 'is_noble_gas': True}, 'hydrogen': {'symbol': 'H', 'number': 1, 'weight': 1.00794, 'is_noble_gas': False}}

Answer (score 0):

```
elements['hydrogen']['is_noble_gas'] = False
elements['hydrogen']['is_noble_gas'] = True
```